# Underpronator Runners

Tags: running, running-shoes, running-training-plan, running-form

I have started this Running Plan http://www.runnersworld.com/getting-started/the-8-week-beginners-program.

I am comfortably in the 4th of it. Since beginning I have been running with these "Fila Coder running shoes"

[image]

Few days ago on searching more on running I got to know that there are different type of runners in the world:

1. Underpronator
2. Neutral
3. Overpronator

I want to run with correct shoes for myself. But I am confused and I have few queries:

1. When I am running slow (not sprinting, not jogging) my left leg goes of middle line of my direction of running i.e. Underpronator(also shoe sole is grazed from outside of heel).  But when I am at full pace (sprinting) I hit hit heel first and and legs remain in Neutral direction. Am I still a Underpronator Runner?
2. Is this a disease or some kind of bad anatomy, my body/legs not designed not born to run? If yes is it curable, by exercising, or practicing correct(neutral) running?
3. Are there pro runners in the world those are Underpronators?
4. I am only going to run 30 mins daily, do I really need expensive shoes designed for underpronator runners?

About Me:
I am 5'8"
172 Pounds
Using "Fitness World: ZETTA COMMERCIAL MOTORIZED TREADMILL"

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's hard to impossible to tell what kind of running/plant style you have by looking down at your feet.

Mainly, this is because you can't really see the mechanics of what your heel/ankle/foot are doing in relation to each other as you go through the land/plant/push cycle, especially when in shoes. It almost requires a rear view of some kind.

I would recommend going to a good running store (Here in the US, I usually recommend [RoadRunner Sports](http://www.roadrunnersports.com/retail) if there is one near) that has treadmill and video capability for gait analysis. At RRS, it's usually free, but it's a worthwhile service. They will show you your gait and plant, and help you pick out shoes geared for your specific style.